# login facebook in my web application Prestashop

Tags: facebook, prestashop

Well I've recently installed and configured an add-on in my website which is built with the cms Prestashop, this add-on is named fbtwgpack (facebook, twitter, google, linkedin full pack) but doesn't work the access to facebook (login) through my facebook application. Indeed, in order to configure this add-on I had to create a facebook application which should allow to login facebook from my website, however when trying login I get the following message:

'The application configuration doesn't allow the provided URL: one or several of the provided URL aren't allowed by the application configuration. They must match the website URL or the main web page URL of the application, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the domains of the application'

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you have to add your website url in your facebook application dashboard.